# Regex conditionals using re.search function

Tags: python, regex

I am using this regex to test a given string for at least one occurrence of:

```
r'[a-z]+[A-Z]+[0-9]+'
```

My `if` statement only returns `true` if string starts with `[a-z]`.

Comment: at least one lower-case + upper-case + one digit. in any order.

Comment: I've tried nearly all variations on the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to test if a string contains at least one each of lowercase, uppercase and digit characters (and consists only of those kinds of characters).

I think the only simple way of solving this (for some definition of simple) is to use a lookahead to look for two of the three categories of character and then a normal pattern checks for the third type of character.

```
re.match(r'(?=[a-zA-Z]*\d)(?=[a-z\d]*[A-Z])[A-Z\d]*[a-z][a-zA-Z\d]*', text)
```

Explanation of the pattern:

1. `(?=[a-zA-Z]*\d)`: a lookahead for any number of letters, followed by a digit.
2. `(?=[a-z\d]*[A-Z])`: a lookahead for any number of lowercase letters or digits, followed by an uppercase letter.
3. `[A-Z\d]*[a-z][a-zA-Z\d]*`: a regular pattern for any number of uppercase or digit characters, followed by a lowercase letter, and then any number of upper, lowercase or digit characters.

If you don't want to limit the matched string to only letters and digits (but still require at least one lowercase, uppercase and digit, among the other kinds of character), you can replace most of the more general character classes in the pattern with `.` (and get a simpler pattern as a bonus): `r'(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z]).*[a-z].*'`

Comment: There are 2 things to note here: we do not know if digits and letters are the only allowed characters in the input. And your bonus expression is not more efficient than `^(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=\D*\d)`. The two split `.*` involve too much backtracking. Using `match` is a smart step though.

Comment: Yes that is correct. The given string has to contain at least a single occurrence of a lower-case character + upper-case character + at least one digit. and no symbols.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [look ahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html):

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qG7iP3/2)

If you want to capture that line:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(.*)$
```

---

As suggested in comments, this is way more efficient:

```
^(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=\D*\d)
```

Comment: Oh, just post [`r"^(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=\D*\d)"`](https://regex101.com/r/mD5hA3/1), it is enough.